# Rails Test Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We are working on a [Library Management Tool](https://github.com/wvulibraries/LibManagementTool/tree/validation-updates) on my model `special_hour.rb`, I am checking that there is no overlap on the dates that are being entered by using a custom validator for both `start_date` and `end_date`.

```
  validate :check_start_date
  validate :check_end_date  

  def check_start_date
    #check if start_date overlaps anything currently set
    check = SpecialHour.where.not(id: id).where("special_id = ?", special_id).where("special_type = ?", special_type).where("start_date <= ?", start_date).where("end_date >= ?", start_date)

    if check.exists?
      errors.add(:start_date, "overlaps currently set special hour.")
    end
  end

  def check_end_date
    #check if end_date overlaps anything currently set
    check = SpecialHour.where.not(id: id).where("special_id = ?", special_id).where("special_type = ?", special_type).where("start_date <= ?", end_date).where("end_date >= ?", end_date)

    if check.exists?
      errors.add(:end_date, "overlaps currently set special hour.")
    end
  end
```

Everything seems to work correctly until I run my tests. If I only run the validate :check_start_date all tests pass but if I run validate :check_end_date I get 3 errors

```
bin/rails test test/models/special_hour_test.rb:9
bin/rails test test/models/special_hour_test.rb:32
bin/rails test test/controllers/admin/special_hours_controller_test.rb:44
```

The two different validations are basically identical except that the date if different. If you need any additional code please look at the github repo. Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

`Failure: SpecialHourTest#test_open_time_should_return_null_for_this_i‌​tem_and_be_allowed_t‌​o_save [/home/libtool/test/models/special_hour_test.rb:35]: the item didn't save there is a problem with the open time saving to the model bin/rails test test/models/special_hour_test.rb:32`

`Failure: SpecialHourTest#test_special_hours_are_valid [/home/libtool/test/models/special_hour_test.rb:10]: the special hour is not valid bin/rails test test/models/special_hour_test.rb:9`

`Failure: Admin::SpecialHoursControllerTest#test_should_update_special‌​_hour [/home/libtool/test/controllers/admin/special_hours_controll‌​er_test.rb:48]: this did not redirect properly bin/rails test test/controllers/admin/special_hours_controller_test.rb:44`

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: Failure:
SpecialHourTest#test_open_time_should_return_null_for_this_item_and_be_allowed_to_save [/home/libtool/test/models/special_hour_test.rb:35]:
the item didn't save there is a problem with the open time saving to the model
bin/rails test test/models/special_hour_test.rb:32

Comment: Failure:
SpecialHourTest#test_special_hours_are_valid [/home/libtool/test/models/special_hour_test.rb:10]:
the special hour is not valid
bin/rails test test/models/special_hour_test.rb:9

Comment: Failure:
Admin::SpecialHoursControllerTest#test_should_update_special_hour [/home/libtool/test/controllers/admin/special_hours_controller_test.rb:48]:
this did not redirect properly

bin/rails test test/controllers/admin/special_hours_controller_test.rb:44

Comment: Make sure to have `.where.not(id: id)` inside the `check_end_date` method as well, because—based on the repo—it looks like you have removed it and that causes an error.

Comment: Yea I had taken it out during testing but it didn't make a difference the error still happens. I put it back and pushed it to the repo.

Comment: What are the error messages now? Are they the same?

Comment: the messages are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue one of my colleagues suggested that I moved my validations from the model to the controller. I have reworked my code and the tests are passing.